# Is $f\in \mathcal{O}(g)$ then is $h\circ f \in \mathcal{O}(h \circ g)$.

Tags: notation

Let be $f,g,h:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ strict increasing. Is the following statement true:

Is $f\in\mathcal{O}(g), $ then is $h \circ f\in \mathcal{O}(h\circ g). $

Comment: Think about $f=2g$ and $h(n) = [e^n]$.

Comment: But my functions go from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and $h(n)$ is real. Or what is $[e^n]$ meaning?

Comment: It's the floor or ceiling function, whichever you prefer. The point is to have a function that grows very quickly.